# How can I debug the code inside Handler function

Tags: http, go, debugging

How can I debug the code inside Handler func? I set a breakpoint inside HandleFunc, click to debug the app, and go to the tracked URL. The debugger does not stop. Ide - golang 20.3. Mac M1. Do I need any additional settings so that the debugger listens to the port?  I go to localhost/test in my browser and see the response, so the handler is executed. But the debugger doesn't stop. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What IDE and/or debugger are you using? (edit) by "golang 20.3" do you perhaps mean GoLand 2020.3?

Comment: @mkopriva IDE - intellij golang 20.3, I could not find anything about the debugger. Before the web, the usual one debugger in IDE was enough for me. Can you advise what to read to debug the web?

Comment: From the image it's not clear whether or not you've properly set a breakpoint for the `/test` handler. You also need to run your code in debug mode for the breakpoints to work. Look at https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2019/02/06/debugging-with-goland-getting-started/ and https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2019/02/14/debugging-with-goland-essentials/ (I've tested it and it works, downloaded the IDE, followed the steps in the links, copied your code, added the breakpoint, launched the app in debug mode, sent a curl request to localhost:8888/test and the breakpoint paused the execution as it should).